# Does C++14 defines function parameters of type 'auto'?

Tags: c++, parameters, auto, c++14, iso

As I was flipping through ISO C++ draft (n4296) for searching the keyword 'auto' - I never find it being mentioned for function-parameters.

Can someone help me? How C++ 14 treats a declaration of follows:

```
void func(auto arg) {}
```

Comment: No, and a conforming C++14 compiler (*cough* Clang) would tell you as much.

Comment: So then how it treats the above example?

Comment: As an error? Not sure exactly what you're asking.

Comment: No. If I'm not mistaken this has been proposed for C++17, though.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo, Yes, as part of Concepts.

Comment: Why would you need this when `template<class T> void func(T arg) {}` would suffice?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious for lambdas. And then, it's nice to have similar syntax for free-standing functions as well.

Answer (score 5):

C++14 can have auto in lambda parameter types but not free functions.